# Editing Navbar or other components in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap on my react project. But I would like to learn all the features of this framework. 
I mean, I saw some pages supported by react-bootstrap. Even, I downloaded the template of pages. But I don't know the usage. Do you have any docs about it? Or any suggestion about how can I understand the usage from a template? 
In short, I can use Navbar with basic commands. But I saw some navbars with images for example. How can I do that? Or how can resize it?

My code is basically like that;

```
<Navbar  bg="dark" variant="dark">
   <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
   <Nav className="mr-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Homee</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
   </Nav>
   <Form inline>
      <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
      <Button variant="outline-info">Search</Button>
   </Form>
</Navbar>
```

**I would like to clarify myself. I know back-end of redux but I feel not enaugh myself at the front-end. Navbar is a just example. I need a doc which have all manageable opportunities.**

Comment: Very general question. Before you learn react-bootstrap, you need to learn props and redux. When you learn these subjects it will be easier.

Comment: @MehmetDemiray I know back-end side like props redux hooks etc. But the problem is, I am not enough at the front-end. This is why I would like to learn react-bootstrap details.

Comment: If the template has made of react-bootstrap then, by looking at the template code and docs provided by react-bootstrap, you can easily get the idea.

Comment: @mav-raj Yes, I am looking that and of course have idea. But if i had docs it would be easier.

Comment: you can get the docs [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts)

Comment: @MehmetDemiray I really don't get the reference to redux in your suggestion. Redux is not related to react-bootstrap in any way

Answer (score 0):

Here is official documentation of
[React Bootstrap - Navbars](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/)

For example Navbar with image;

```
  <Navbar bg="light">
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Brand link</Navbar.Brand>
  </Navbar>
  <br />
  <Navbar bg="light">
    <Navbar.Brand>Brand text</Navbar.Brand>
  </Navbar>
  <br />
  <Navbar bg="dark">
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
      <img
        src="/logo.svg"
        width="30"
        height="30"
        className="d-inline-block align-top"
        alt="React Bootstrap logo"
      />
    </Navbar.Brand>
  </Navbar>
  <br />
  <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
      <img
        alt=""
        src="/logo.svg"
        width="30"
        height="30"
        className="d-inline-block align-top"
      />{' '}
      React Bootstrap
    </Navbar.Brand>
  </Navbar>
```

[All navbar props](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbar-props)

Comment: I saw this. But it's not Navbar with image. It's just adding Logo. Like this website's stackoverflow logo.